# flexslider / wordpress / images below each other

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I followed this tutorial: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/adding-a-responsive-jquery-slider-to-your-wordpress-theme/ but the images get displayed below each other. I looked it up with firebug and the script/css don't get loaded:

```
function wptuts_slider_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'flex-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/slider/css/flexslider.css' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'flex-script', get_template_directory_uri() .  '/inc/slider/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_slider_scripts' );
```

The url is the right one. I also tried to include those scripts in the header.php - it worked but then the image get display:none....

Answer (score 0):

With `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );` you are adding jQuery but that is not necessary since jQuery is already integrated in WordPress.

If jQuery is added twice, problems will occur, so remove that line and try again.